# Standard colors in QtCreator (KDE)

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, archlinux, kde-plasma

I have just got started trying QtCreator today, on Arch Linux with KDE (BreezeDark theme).

Below this, there is a picture of the standard "Hello World" application in Qt with QML (QtQuick). I can't find out why the text in the button is white, as I haven't changed a single thing apart from adding the button..

To be clear, there is text in the button, it's just not visible due to the color.
[image]

Comment: Can you show us some code? Is it really just a `Button` with only `text` assigned?

Comment: Yes, it's really just a button with only text.. I don't have access to the code atm, sorry.

Comment: @Mitch

`   Button {
        id: button1
        x: 20
        y: 16
        text: "TEST"
    }`

This is my code.

Comment: That's really weird. The Desktop [`ButtonStyle`](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtquickcontrols.git/tree/src/controls/Styles/Desktop/ButtonStyle.qml) uses [`StyleItem`](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtquickcontrols.git/tree/src/controls/Private/qquickstyleitem.cpp), which uses `QStyleOptionButton`. I guess the palette comes from the system theme. Perhaps there's a KDE theme plugin that's buggy?

Comment: I have asked the same question at the Qt forums, and got a reply that there is a bug in QtQuick Controls 1.5. I have switched to 2.0 and the problem is gone. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

There turns out to be a bug in `QtQuick Controls 1.5`. Switch to `2.0` and the problem should be solved.